# False alarm on zabbix trigger in web scenario

Tags: apache2, zabbix

I have a website whose running on Apache Server. I want recieve a notification every time when a web site falling down.I created a trigger:

```
{Zabbix server:web.test.fail[http:example.com].sum(#6)}>0
```

But website running not well and i receive a error every 6 hours or 30 minutes.

**How writing a trigger which send me a notification after 12 minutes (for example) error site?**

I just want to my trigger didn't catch a small error of web site. Only global crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the min / max function for this purpose.

For example

```
{Zabbix server:web.test.fail[http:example.com].min(12m)}>0
```

The trigger will work if the site is unavailable within 12 minutes.

And with this example

```
{Zabbix server:web.test.fail[http:example.com].max(12m)}<1
```

You can return the trigger to working condition if the site is available for more than 12 minutes

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/ru/manual/appendix/triggers/functions

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the number of attempts in web scenario to eliminate some of the false errors.